# Database Sequence in Repository layer in a DB-agnostic way using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query to fetch a sequence of the form:

```java
@Repository
public class GetSequenceRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public String getSequenceUsingNativeQuery() {
            // POSTGRES Syntax
            return entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval ('my_custom_seq')")
                                .getSingleResult().toString();
    }
}
```

Since the syntax is different for Postgres, MySQL and Oracle; I want to create a query to get sequence value in a database-agnostic manner.

I want something like `@Sequencegenerator` but at the Repository layer. Is there implementation of `@Sequencegenerator` at Repository layer.

Note:

I have a sequence already present in Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()
   .unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
   .getIdentifierGenerator("your.hibernate.entity.name")
   .generate(entityManager.unwrap(SharedSessionContractImplementor.class), null)
```

If the sequence is not mapped for an entity, you need to construct a IdentifierGenerator yourself:

```
IdentifierGeneratorFactory identifierGeneratorFactory = new DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory();
identifierGeneratorFactory.setDialect(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class).getDialect());
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("sequence_name", "YOUR_NAME");
IdentifierGenerator identifierGenerator = identifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator("sequence", StringType.INSTANCE, properties);
identifierGenerator.generate(entityManager.unwrap(SharedSessionContractImplementor.class), null);
```

Comment: I do not want to create a sequence. My scenario is such that a sequence already exists but I need to query in a database-agnostic way.

Comment: This will not create a new sequence on the database but create a sequence generator (a Hibernate concept) which you can use to fetch values from the sequence in a DB agnostic way.